# Mid-century table: Is it worth re-veneering?

Tags: wood-repair, veneer

I have this mid-century round dining table. The table top is veneer, and it's damaged with bubbles and scratches.

The cost for fixing/re-veneering seems to be between $400 and $800.

Is it worth doing for this table? It is very sturdy and seems to be from the 1950 or 1960s.

See the image below and more detailed images [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/marekfoto/albums/72157670168796833).

[image]

Comment: Not worth paying someone to do. Doing it yourself, maybe, if you are fond of this table; resale value is likely to be minimal. Note that simply using an iron to melt the adhesive may be all that's needed to reattach the existing veneer.

Comment: Concur with @keshlam on all points. It is definitely worth trying an iron to soften the glue and re-attach the veneer. There are various tips to help achieve good results doing this, including ironing through paper (helps prevent scorching) and *lightly* dampening the surface prior to heating. Ask a fresh Question on this if you like but there is lots of help on this subject to be found online.

Comment: Is it possible to rephrase this question so it won't gather opinionated answers?  Whether it is worth it or not is highly subjective and there is no right or wrong answer.

Comment: I agree with Steven as far as the question goes. For example, perhaps the table has high sentimental value, and you also have enough money in the bank that a few hundred dollars is pocket change, and so of course it's worth it. We can't really make that kind of judgment here. You tell us: Is it worth $400-$800 *to you* to have somebody else do it, or isn't it?

Comment: You can read it as an objective question: Is this table worth $400 or more? It looks like the answer is no. The tips about using an iron to try and fix the bubbles are great. I'll try!

Comment: As you say Markus, as written, this question essentially comes down to "is this table worth more than $400.  However, I don't think that helps make the question a good fit for our site. Value is inherently subjective (the fact that people value things differently is an essential part of commerce).  If you're asking for the market value, unfortunately that is off-topic for our site. We are focused on the craft of woodworking and problems people face when creating things with wood.  All that being said, I do think it's possible to phrase this question in a way that makes it on-topic.